# A computional efficient bijective $ C^1 $ function that maps $ \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{+} $ and it's inverse is also $C^1$.

Tags: real-analysis, computability

I'm looking for a iso function that maps reals to positive reals the inverse also needs to be $C^1$. But it need it needs to be efficient to be calculated on computers. Using maps like

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{x} - 2  & \text{if}\ 0 < x \leq \dfrac{1}{2}\\ 
\dfrac{1}{x-1} + 2 & \text{if} \ \dfrac{1}{2} < x < 1
\end{cases}
$$

Do not work very well since when $x$ approaches the interval bounds $0, 1$, the function explodes and goes quickly to infinity, taking too much memory space for small increases.

Also I need it to be $C^1$ since I'm looking for their derivatives.

Comment: The exponential?

Comment: The inverse needs to be $C^1$  too. Using exponentials leads to invalid logs on the inverse.

Comment: You defined $f$ just on $(0,1)$. Maybe you need a function $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$? In that case $x\mapsto \tan\left(\pi x-\frac{\pi}2\right)$ will do it.

Comment: Please write up carefully and correctly what you need. At the moment title and body of the question disagree.

Comment: You're right, I will fix.

Comment: I don't understand your comment on the inverse. If the target space is $\mathbb{R}^+$ then the inverse will blow up near $0$. Up to that point the logarithm is as smooth as you can wish.

Comment: What is "iso"?$\,$